# Naming convention for audio track files in Plex Media Server

Tags: audio, naming, plex

How to name audio track files for movies (*.ac3) in Plex Media Server so that this track can be selected in the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always mux them into the main movie container (mkv or mp4). This way you may also set different track options for every audio track.